# How can I use for loops to make this code shorter?Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am basically getting information from the user, have the input placed in a list and ask them for the account number. I also have them enter their name and balance inserted into two other list. I want it to only print their specific number,name, and balance based on what account number they have entered using a loop instead of an if and elif

```
 count = 0
    while count != 4: 
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    customers.append(name)
    num = int(input("Enter account number: "))
    acctnum.append(num)
    bal = float(input("Enter Current Balance:$ "))
    print()
    balance.append(bal)
    count = count + 1
personal = int(input("Enter account number: "))
withdraw = int(input("Enter amount to be withdrawn: "))


if personal in acctnum:

   if (acctnum.index(personal)) == 0:
       print()
       print("\nCustomer name: ", customers[0])
       print("Account Number: ",acctnum[0])
       print("Balance: ", balance[0])
       newbal = balance[0] 
       print()

   elif (acctnum.index(personal)) == 1:
      print("\nCustomer name: ", customers[1])
      print("Account Number: ",acctnum[1])
      print("Balance: ", balance[1])
      newbal = balance[1] 
      print()

   elif (acctnum.index(personal)) == 2:
      print("\nCustomer name: ", customers[2])
      print("Account Number: ",acctnum[2])
      print("Balance: ", balance[2])
      newbal = balance[2] 
      print()

   elif (acctnum.index(personal)) == 3:
      print("\nCustomer name: ", customers[3])
      print("Account Number: ",acctnum[3])
      print("Balance: ", balance[3])
      newbal = balance[3] 
      print()

   elif (acctnum.index(personal)) == 4:
      print("\nCustomer name: ", customers[4])
      print("Account Number: ",acctnum[4])
      print("Balance: ", balance[4])
      newbal = balance[4] 
      print()
```

Comment: Perhaps you would like to fix your indentation. What you have posted will not even run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this loop structure would reduce the necessary `elif` statements:

```
if personal in acctnum:
    for i in range(4):
        if (acctnum.index(personal)) == i:
            print()
            print("\nCustomer name: ", customers[i])
            print("Account Number: ",acctnum[i])
            print("Balance: ", balance[i])
            newbal = balance[i] 
            print()
```

You could always replace the 4 in `for i in range(4)` with a variable that tracks the number of accounts.